# In Python, how do I get my list to input into my functions to get the averages from user input?

Tags: python, list, function, input, average

Here is the code I have and I cannot seem to get my list to be input into my functions. I know I have to name it but every time I define it as a function I get a print out that makes no sense. Please help, I need to somehow get an end result that looks like this:

```
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  4

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -3

Enter a number (-9999 to end): -15

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  0

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  10

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  22

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -9999
```

The list of all numbers entered is:

```
[4, -3, -15, 0, 10, 22]
```

The dictionary with averages is:

```
{'AvgPositive': 12.0, 'AvgNonPos': -6.0, 'AvgAllNum': 3.0}
```

Here's my updated code:

```
numList = []
k = 0
while True:
    k = k+1
    userInput = input("Enter any integer, positive or negatve, or -9999 to end:")
    if userInput == '-9999':
        break
    numList.append(int(userInput))

print(numList)

def numAvg(numList):
    sum(numList)/len(numList)

def posAvg(numList):
    sum = 0
    k = 0
    for n in numList:
        if n > 0:
            sum = sum + n
            k = k + 1
        avgPositive = sum/k
        return(avgPositive)

def nonPosAvg(numList):
    sum = 0
    k = 0
    for n in numList:
        if n <= 0:
            sum = sum + n
            k = k + 1
        avgNonPositive = sum/k
        return(avgNonPositive)

print("The dictionary with averages is:")

averages = {}
averages['nonPosAvg'] = nonPosAvg(numList)
averages['posAvg'] = posAvg(numList)
averages['allNumAvg'] = numAvg(numList)

print(averages)
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Your list is called `numList` and you are appending to `num`.

Comment: It is giving me a list that only includes the number -9999 and then it doesn't run my functions. it says there is an issue with line 45: posAvg(numList) Most likely because it is only recognizing -9999 as part of the list. That is the only integer I do not want in the list, all others input by the user should be in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to loop and take input until user enter -9999:

```
num_list = []
while True
    x = input("Enter a number (-9999 to end): ")
    if x == '-9999':
        break
    num_list.append(int(x))
```

the above code will take all number from user into list called my_list.

total avg:

```
tol_avg = sum(num_list)/len(num_list)
```

for avg positive:

```
pos_num = [ x for x in num_list if x>0]
pos_avg = sum(pos_num)/len(pos_num)
```

for negative replace `x>=0` to `x<0`:

```
neg_num = [ x for x in num_list if x<=0]
neg_avg = sum(neg_num)/len(neg_num)
```

for dictionary:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['tot_avg'] = tot_avg
my_dict['pos_avg'] = pos_avg
my_dict['neg-avg'] = neg_avg
print(my_dict)
```

this should be this:

```
def numAvg(numList):
    return sum(numList)/len(numList)
```

return must be out of for in all case:

```
def posAvg(numList):
    sum = 0
    k = 0
    for n in numList:
        if n > 0:
            sum = sum + n
            k = k + 1
    avgPositive = sum/k
    return(avgPositive)
```

don't use `sum` as variable name, its built-in fucntion

Comment: the negative is supposed to include 0, It's actually supposed to be non-positive numbers. but this really helped! I just am having issues with the dictionary print, thank you!

Comment: I am getting this now: 'The dictionary with averages is:
{'nonPosAvg': <function nonPosAvg at 0x02AAB348>, 'allNumAvg': <function numAvg at 0x02AA69C0>, 'posAvg': <function posAvg at 0x02A724B0>}'

Comment: can you update all your code so i can see??

Comment: I updated it for you

Comment: @BrandyMcIntosh You need to call `nonPosAvg(numList)` not just `nonPosAvg`. That's why you are getting `<function nonPosAvg at 0x02AAB348>` as your output.

Comment: I just realized this lol. but now it still says that the non positive average is dividing by 0 but with the counter and having 3 non positive numbers it should be dividing by 3

Comment: @BrandyMcIntosh check the updated code avg and return must be out of for loop

Comment: I finally fixed it! Thanks again, I hope seeing these little mistakes just gets easier with time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the functions inside your dictionary. At the moment, you are calling the functions but the results aren't being put anywhere.

Get rid of:

```
numAvg(numList)
posAvg(numList)
nonPosAvg(numList)
```

And change:

```
averages = {'AvgPositive': posAvg, 'AvgNonPos': nonPosAvg, 'AvgAllNum': numAvg}
```

to

```
averages = {'AvgPositive': posAvg(numList), 'AvgNonPos': nonPosAvg(numList), 'AvgAllNum': numAvg(numList)}
```

Comment: When I did it said that somehow the avgNonPositive is being divided by zero even though there are three non negative numbers being input.

Comment: @BrandyMcIntosh That's because if there are no Non-negative numbers, k=0, and you are trying to do `avgNegative = sum/k` which gives you the error. You could put an extra if statement in there to check `if k=0`, and if it is, just return 0.

Comment: I thought by putting the counter in of k = k + 1 for each loop that it would end up being 3 by the time it got to the 3rd non negative number.

Comment: For you avgNonPositive function, `k = k + 1` is only running when `if n <= 0:`. So if your list is [1,2,3], `k = k + 1` will never run and you will be dividing by 0.

Comment: The list I input was [4,-3,-15,0,10,22]

Comment: Ok I found the bug. Its because you have your `avgPositive = sum/k` and `return(avgPositive)` inside your for loop. You need to run that code AFTER the for loop is done, not during it. So just de-indent those lines in each function and it should work given you list has both positive and negative numbers.

Comment: Wow, it was right there in front of me the whole time. :) Thank you for all of your help!